# Binding list into datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml

Having hard time binding a list to the datagrid:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}">
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Header="Item" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Qty" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalPrice}" Header="Price" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
```

Code behind:

```
public IList<SalesItem> ProductList = new List<SalesItem>();

public void LoadProduct(Product product)
        {
            SalesItem item = new SalesItem { ProductName = product.Name, Quantity = 1, TotalPrice = product.Price };
            ProductList.Add(item);
        }
```

It does not load.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataGrid won't know when the ProductList is updated... make a ObservableCollection like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<SalesItem> ProductList = new ObservableCollection<SalesItem>();
```

**EDIT:**

Is the binding working at all? Name your control/window Root and bind to that element

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="Root">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgProductList" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root,Path=ProductList}">
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Header="Item" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Qty" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalPrice}" Header="Price" />
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I add in this.dgProductList.ItemsSource = ProductList; after the InitializeComponent, it works, but the problem is it add one row by default...

Comment: Yees, I was trying that to... and it looks like datagrid needs the list binding before the list is edited...

Comment: Yes, the thing is I won'r want the deafult emoty columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind your collection to

```
ObservableCollection<SalesItem>
```

The UI is probably not notified when you add a product.